# mysqldump not found in jenkinsfile

Tags: mysql, docker, jenkins, gogs

When I used mysqldump command in Jenkinsfile of Gogs (git) to backup my database, I got an error in Jenkins build says that mysqldump not found, even I build first mysql container. Anyone can help ?

Thanks,

Mahmoud

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. How are you building the container and what's your pipeline code? Hard to help without any kind of detail

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mysql client on your jenkins server?

Maybe when you builded your projec with jenkins it not foud a mysqldump in your jenkins server, then you will need to install the mysql client to use mysqldump, to install mysql client you can use these line:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.1
```

Comment: Sorry Brayan but where should I put exactly because I tried to add it in Jenkinsfile but it didn't work.

Comment: Your jenkinsfile run it on your jenkins server, you need to install mysql client in your jenkins server and then your jenkinsfile can execute your dump file.

Comment: you won't write the apt-get install in your jenkinsfile, you will need to install the mysql client on your jenkis server

Comment: I did install mysql client in Jenkins server and added mysql-database plugin then tested again, I got the error below :

mysqldump: Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")" when trying to connect
the input device is not a TTY